# Powershell 5.0 SHA-3?

Tags: windows, powershell

Does anyone know if it is possible to **calculate SHA-3** in power shell **5.0** ?

If it is not the case are there any open source 3rd party software i can use ?

Comment: .Net Framework does not have a SHA-3 class, so Powershell, does not have it.  As for theirs-party software, that might exist, it wouldn't be on topic for me recommend one so find them yourself

Comment: A google search returns [Use PowerShell To Calculate the Hash of a File](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/03/25/use-powershell-to-calculate-the-hash-of-a-file/): 
    MD5 
    SHA1
    SHA256
    SHA384
    SHA512
    RIPEM160

Comment: Thanks for the comments Ramhound and DavidPostill , i think i will use Crypto-JS library instead  Since the .net Framework does not have the SHA-3 Class : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30109958/calculating-sha-3-hash-in-java  .

Comment: @FouadMaidine, don't forget that it's trivial to call .NET libraries from PowerShell, so if you can find a third party .NET library out there that does SHA-3, then you could use that.